# Unable to open word file on browser using php

Tags: php

I want to open a word file on browser using php. I have read on somewhere that it could not open on browser and you should use iframe for that. Can any one suggest me some solution if I dont want to open it using iframe. I might use this code to view word file on browser.

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: inline');
header('Content-type: application/msword'); 
readfile('filename');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: is there a problem with the code above? It's unclear what your issue is, other than a vague fear about a potential difficulty. Have you actually tried it in the various major browsers? Bear in mind that Word format is not a browser-native format, so usually it will only display inline within the browser window if the browser has a suitable plugin installed. Otherwise it generally just gets downloaded. I don't think using an iframe will make any difference, if the browser doesn't have any way of displaying that type of file.

Comment: yes i have tried this code and its getting download the original php file...

Comment: i have also tried with iframe and i am getting an issue: docs.google.com refused to connect..here is my code that i have used for it...echo "<iframe src='https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://192.168.0.56/orangehrm/admin/images/'.$file.'&embedded=true' width='100%'></iframe>";

Comment: "i have tried this code and its getting download the original php file." ...you mean you see your PHP code displayed in the browser? If so, that means that PHP is not properly installed and configured in your webserver

Comment: The main problem with your iframe seems to be that your webserver is on your local network and not visible on public internet. How do you imagine google was going to access your file from their server? It's not magic, there would need to be a route to your server from the google server and I can see (from the URL) that there is not. Also the sample URL you gave above appears to include the word `$file` instead of an actual file. Is that another symptom of PHP not executing properly?

Comment: can u suggest me any solution what i need to do ?

Comment: i have actual word document in my $file....

Comment: Did you understand anything I wrote? The main thing you need to do is host your word document on a publicly accessible server. If you need PHP to decide which file is being shown, and inject the filename into the URL, then you need to make sure that server has PHP installed and running on it properly. (N.B. It's possible, but probably not advisable, to make your local webserver accessible over the net using port forwarding on your router, but it's a bit of a security risk. It might be ok temporarily just for testing this feature.)

Comment: P.S. you said "i have actual word document in my $file"....I can't see the code you used to create the $file variable, nor can I see how you tried to include that in the iframe code, so I don't know if you've done that right or not. So if PHP _is_ running, but you haven't written the code properly, it might explain why it didn't turn $file into the name of a document. Get that working, and publish your code and files on a public server, and you might have a chance of it working. If you need more help with the actual code, then show it here.

Comment: $file = $_GET['FV']; i am using this code to get the file name of doc file.. and it is successfully getting the file name. but the issue is it does not showing it on iframe with google docs.. echo '<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://192.168.0.56/orangehrm/admin/images/".$file."&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>'; and i am including the file name variable in iframe.. but it said google docs refused to connect..

Comment: echo '<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://192.168.0.56/orangehrm/admin/images/"'.$file.'&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>';

Comment: See again my earlier comment where I wrote "The main problem with your iframe seems to be that your webserver is on your local network and not visible on public internet. How do you imagine google was going to access your file from their server? It's not magic, there would need to be a route to your server from the google server and I can see (from the URL) that there is not."

Comment: And I already told you the possible solutions to it as well. Please do read the information you are given more carefully

Comment: echo '<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://192.168.0.56/orangehrm/admin/images/'.$file.'&embedded=true" style="width: 100%;"></iframe>';
the error message is now getting change. its hows that no preview available.i think i should change the file permission then it should work fine... i have used chmod($dirfilename, 0755); this function for that but it does not work...

Comment: i have also tried this code.. but it actually downloading the original file instead of showing on a browser.. is there any header i am missing into that ??                                                                             
     $filename = "/var/www/orangehrm/admin/images/". $file;
               $AttachmentsURL = str_replace("/var/www/orangehrm", $GLOBALS["BrowserURLStart"], $filename);
          header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; FileName="'. $AttachmentsURL.'"');
        readfile($AttachmentsURL);

Comment: "it actually downloading the original file instead of showing on a browser" ...yes because browsers cannot show Word files, it is not a file format they understand (unlike, for example, HTML files or JPG files). They would need an extra plugin installed in the browser which allows it to understand the Word format. Again, I mentioned this in the very first comment I wrote. And again, I feel like you are not actually looking very carefully at what I'm saying.

Comment: P.S. also, with `Content-Disposition: attachment`... using the `attachment` setting will be understood by the browser as an instruction to download instead of displaying inline. So even if the browser was able to display the document directly, it would not do so because of this header. Did you [research the meaning of this header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition), or just copy it because you saw it used somewhere else? Don't just blindly copy things you don't understand. It's incredibly easy to look things up online these days.

Comment: `Content-Disposition: inline` would be more helpful to you - **if** the browser actually has a plugin to allow it to display a Word document. But you have no way to guarantee that your users will be able or willing to install such a thing. To be honest I think you would be better going back to using the iframe idea, which will work fine as long as you move your website to a public webserver (or store the documents in Google Drive).